# dynamic number within for looping in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dynamic, integer

hello i have trouble in for-loop code block 
my instructor give me assignement only use variables and array

2- exclude name start with **A**

3-Put before names dynamic Integer.

Original Code :

```
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Eman", "Mahmoud","Ameer", "Osama", "Sameh"];
```

```
let letter = "a";
```

Should Output be like this:

```
// Output
"1 => Sayed"
"2 => Eman"
"3 => Mahmoud"
"4 => Osama"
"5 => Sameh"
```

I do like this:

```
for (let z = 0; z< friends.length; z++) {
    
  if (friends[z][0] === letter.toUpperCase()) {
    continue;
  }

    console.log(`${z} => ${friends[z]}"`);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a counter for the output lines.

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Eman", "Mahmoud", "Ameer", "Osama", "Sameh"],
    letter = "a",
    counter = 0;

letter = letter.toUpperCase();

for (let z = 0; z < friends.length; z++) {
    if (friends[z][0] === letter) continue;
    console.log(`${++counter} => ${friends[z]}`);
}
```

An even shorter approach works without an index for the array.

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Eman", "Mahmoud", "Ameer", "Osama", "Sameh"],
    letter = "a",
    counter = 0;

letter = letter.toUpperCase();

for (const friend of friends) {
    if (friend[0] === letter) continue;
    console.log(`${++counter} => ${friend}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, use a variable and increment it after the if block.

```
var cnt = 0;
for (let z = 0; z< friends.length; z++) {

  if (friends[z][0] === letter.toUpperCase()) {
    continue;
  }

  cnt++;

  console.log(`"${cnt} => ${friends[z]}"`);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code...

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Eman", "Mahmoud", "Ameer", "Osama", "Sameh"];

for (let z = 0; z < friends.length; z++) {

  if (friends[z][0] === 'A') {
    continue;
  }

  console.log(`${z} => ${friends[z]}`);
}
```

or...

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Eman", "Mahmoud", "Ameer", "Osama", "Sameh"];
let i = 1;

for (let name of friends) {
  if (name[0] != 'A') {
    console.log(i + ' => ' + name);
    i++;
  }
}
```

simply!